# Entangled electrons: no interference (Ballentine)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference

Ballentine's textbook presents an experiment with entangled electrons (page 271 of the pdf, problem 9.6) whose resolution of the "paradox" can be found in the chapter "solutions" (pages 646-647 of the pdf):

https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics441/online/Ballentine.pdf

The solution is:

The probability density on the screen for the whole ensemble will be **[|ψ1(x)|² + |ψ2(x)|²]/2 which exhibits no interference.**

OK.
That's right, of course, but I have 2 questions:

1. What in the **mathematical formula allows us to deduce** that there is no interference ? I don't see what makes it obvious.
2. Whatever happens, the electrons arriving on the screen always have **the same spin (up)**. Since they always have the same spin, **what physical explanation** prevents the electrons from interfering ?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Please include a description of the setup and the resolution in the question itself;  links often die, making the question useless to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no interference because the result is the same as if you had sent individual electrons, half of them with wave function $\psi_1$ (so they make a pattern on the screen in the shape of $|\psi_1|^2$) and half with wavefunction $\psi_2$ (shape of $|\psi_2|^2$) - giving a total of $1/2(|\psi_1|^2+|\psi_2|^2)$. The fact that the electrons are in a superposition doesn't affect the result. Interference is, in some sense, defined by the result being different from the result you would get without making a superposition. So a result like $$1/2(|\psi_1+\psi_2|^2)=1/2(|\psi_1|^2+|\psi_2|^2 +\psi_1^*\psi_2+\psi_2^*\psi_1)$$
shows interference as long as $\psi_1^*\psi_2+\psi_2^*\psi_1$ isn't zero.